# CSS display: table or display:table-cell img in safari and internt explorer

Tags: css, safari, internet-explorer-8, joomla3.0

Hey all thank you in advances for taking a look at this post!

Ok down to the problem. I have been working on a jooomla 3.0 site now upgraded to a 3.5 site using the Helix 3 framework. i was having an issue with centering the menus and i discovered css display: table property, this solved the problem. i tried to used the dispaly:table property with images in 2 places on the home page. it works just fine in Opera, Fire Fox, Chrome, and Android as well as the browser on the ipad.

Below is the html code

```
<div class="booktable">
<div class="bcell"><a href="http://www.redemption-press.com/shop/product/21556" target="_blank"><img src="images/sidebar-main.png" alt="" /></a></div>
<div class="bcell"><form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top"><input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_s-xclick" /> <input name="hosted_button_id" type="hidden" value="XZF7EPBFS629N" /> <input alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="images/Organize_His_Way_Teachers_Guide-1.jpg" type="image" /></form></div>
<div class="bcell"><form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top"><input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_s-xclick" /> <input name="hosted_button_id" type="hidden" value="P3R35E3YK7MLY" /> <input alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="images/all_things_new.png" type="image" /></form></div>
</div>
<div class="pcell">
<p>All Things New is a compilation of short vignettes that will help liberate you from the entanglement of clutter, and show you how to live a life of space, freedom and peace. I pray that after reading All Things New you too will be transformed from munching through life to soaring high on newly sprouted wing</p></div>
```

Here is the css:

```
/*----buttons on home page ----*/

.customimae_ads { 
width: 100%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-bottom: 2rem;
display: table;
background-color: #BBF4FB;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 1rem;
border: 1px solid #02369b;

}
.acell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #02369b;
  box-shadow: .3125rem .3125rem .3125rem #888888;


}
.customimae_ads img { 
width:100%;
}


/*---bookstore---*/
.booktable { 
width: 100%;
display: table;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: .5rem;
overflow-x: hidden;
background-color: #BBF4FB;
border: 1px solid #02369b;
margin-bottom: .625rem;
}

.bcell { 
display:table-cell;
}

.bcell input[type="image"] { 
width: 100%;
}

.bcell img { 
 width: 100%;
}
```

safari render image
[safari table display issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOrnv.jpg)

internet explorer
[click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szgCe.jpg)

```css
/*----buttons on home page ----*/

.customimae_ads { 
width: 100%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
 display: table;
 background-color: #BBF4FB;
 border-collapse: separate;
 border-spacing: 1rem;
 border: 1px solid #02369b;
  
}
.acell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #02369b;
  box-shadow: .3125rem .3125rem .3125rem #888888;
  

}
.customimae_ads img { 
width:100%;
}


/*---bookstore---*/
.booktable { 
width: 100%;
display: table;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: .5rem;
overflow-x: hidden;
background-color: #BBF4FB;
border: 1px solid #02369b;
margin-bottom: .625rem;
}

.bcell { 
display:table-cell;

}

.bcell input[type="image"] { 
width: 100%;

}

.bcell img { 
 width: 100%;

}
.pcell { 
float: right;
width 50%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="booktable">
<div class="bcell"><a href="http://www.redemption-press.com/shop/product/21556" target="_blank"><img src="images/sidebar-main.png" alt="" /></a></div>
<div class="bcell"><form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top"><input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_s-xclick" /> <input name="hosted_button_id" type="hidden" value="XZF7EPBFS629N" /> <input alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="images/Organize_His_Way_Teachers_Guide-1.jpg" type="image" /></form></div>
<div class="bcell"><form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top"><input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_s-xclick" /> <input name="hosted_button_id" type="hidden" value="P3R35E3YK7MLY" /> <input alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="images/all_things_new.png" type="image" /></form></div>
</div>
<div class="pcell">
<p> All Things New is a compilation of short vignettes that will help liberate you from the entanglement of clutter, and show you how to live a life of space, freedom and peace. I pray that after reading All Things New you too will be transformed from munching through life to soaring high on newly sprouted wing</p>
</div>
```

Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I would like to see the working code. Can you provide a link?

Comment: http://ekm16.anastasioumedia.com

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: how do you you fix the so these items display correctly? is there anything in my code that is causing a conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS fixed the issues in Safari for me.

```
.booktable {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  padding: 0.5em 0.25em 0;
}

.bcell {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 0.25em;
}
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]